# Looping over objects and methods in arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial);
  while(bmm150_1.begin()){
    Serial.println("bmm150_1 init failed, Please try again!");
    delay(1000);
  } Serial.println("bmm150_1 init success!");

  bmm150_1.setPresetMode(BMM150_PRESETMODE_HIGHACCURACY);

  bmm150_1.setRate(BMM150_DATA_RATE_10HZ);

  bmm150_1.setMeasurementXYZ();
  
// I want to copy everything above, and everywhere that references "bmm150_1" insert "bmm150_2", then the same for bmm150_3, etc. 
}
```

Hey yall, Im working in the arduino IDE with a snippet of my code above. I have a class from which the "bmm150_1" object is created. I want to create several more of these, and then repeat the entire block of code above (within the setup) for bmm150_2, bmm150_3, etc.

How should I go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a reference to the object you want set up, then set it up.

```cpp
void setup(type_of_object & object_to_set_up) 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial);
  while(object_to_set_up.begin()){
    Serial.println("bmm150_1 init failed, Please try again!");
    delay(1000);
  } Serial.println("bmm150_1 init success!");

  object_to_set_up.setPresetMode(BMM150_PRESETMODE_HIGHACCURACY);

  object_to_set_up.setRate(BMM150_DATA_RATE_10HZ);

  object_to_set_up.setMeasurementXYZ();
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
setup(bmm150_1);
setup(bmm150_2);
setup(bmm150_3);
```

Adjust example to tastes. For example, it's unlikely you want to or need to set up the serial port for each object you need set up and may want to pass in additional parameters to customize the configuration.

Side note: Consider using a constructor rather than a set-up function. It really sucks when you forget to call set-up and have an improperly configured object floating around. If you do the work in the constructor you know all instances are valid.

Expanding to cover all of the likely parameters necessary to fully generalize the interface:

```cpp
void setup(type_of_object & object_to_set_up,
           const char * object_name,
           int preset_mode,
           int  data_rate)  
{
  while(!Serial);
  while(object_to_set_up.begin()){
    Serial.print(object_name);
    Serial.println(" init failed, Please try again!");
    delay(1000);
  } 
  Serial.print(object_name);
  Serial.println(" init success!");

  object_to_set_up.setPresetMode(preset_mode);

  object_to_set_up.setRate(data_rate);

  object_to_set_up.setMeasurementXYZ();
}
```

Now the usage is

```
setup(bmm150_1, 
      "bmm150_1", 
      BMM150_PRESETMODE_HIGHACCURACY, 
      BMM150_DATA_RATE_10HZ);
```

Comment: thanks! one detail though, how would i change the print statements in the while loop? in your code you have it as a fixed string saying "bmm150_1", is there a way to convert a function input to a string that can then be printed?

Comment: @Fil That would be one of the "additional parameters" you may want to pass in.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what Arduino offers by way of string classes. With a full C++ Standard Library, you'd add a `const std::string & object_name` parameter and `Serial.println((object_name + " init failed, Please try again!").c_str());`, but without a decent string class, you're better off passing in `const char * object_name` and then `Serial.print(object_name); Serial.println(" init failed, Please try again!");`